# why AsyncTaskMethodBuilder use Task internally instead of TaskCompletionSource

Tags: c#, .net

When we mark a method as async and use await inside the Compiler transforms the async function into a state machine
for example,

```
private static async Task<String> MyMethodAsync(Int32 argument) { ... }
```

get transformed to

```
[DebuggerStepThrough, AsyncStateMachine(typeof(StateMachine))]
private static Task<String> MyMethodAsync(Int32 argument) {
   StateMachine stateMachine = new StateMachine() {
      m_builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<String>.Create(),
      m_state = -1, // Initialize state machine location
      m_argument = argument // Copy arguments to state machine fields
   };

   // Start executing the state machine
   stateMachine.m_builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
   return stateMachine.m_builder.Task; // Return state machine's Task
}
```

and the definition of AsyncTaskMethodBuilder is

```
public struct AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<TResult> {
   private Task<TResult> m_task;
   ...

   public void SetResult(TResult result) {
      ... // call Task's TrySetResult method
   }
}
```

From my undestanding, TaskCompletionSource is used to create Task objects that don't execute code, which is the perfect case in the state machine as it create a dummy task (`stateMachine.m_builder.Task`) retuned to the caller, and once worker threads finishe original tasks, the state machine will call SetResult via its `m_builder` member to manually add the result to the dummy task, so why AsyncTaskMethodBuilder doesn't use TaskCompletionSource?

Comment: Given that `TaskCompletionSource` is implemented using `Task`, I would imagine that this is to avoid using an additional class in the implementation. But only the implementers would really be able to answer this question.

Comment: If you look at the source for `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`, you'll see lots of commentary around performance tuning. Using a *dedicated type* that can be precisely tuned to the *needs* of the compiler may be a better choice here than using a *general purpose* type.

Answer (score 3):

> why AsyncTaskMethodBuilder doesn't use TaskCompletionSource?

The `Task` type has many APIs that are internal (only available to the BCL). `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder` can just call them directly.

`TaskCompletionSource<T>` is for completing Promise Tasks, and if anyone else outside the BCL had to implement `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`, then they'd have to use TCS.

In other words: it's an optimization that isn't available to you or me.